# Embedding different applications in a Win Form in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, embed

How to embedd two different applications in a single windows form?

Suppose I have an application abour calculations and about web cam and I want them to show in a form?

Don't need only proccess.start()....

Comment: Do they have to be separate applications? Do you have access to source code for both or either?

Comment: no, i dont have source code...
It's Idea exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the [SetParent Windows API call](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html).

To do this, you'd need to import the relevant API call:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Add using directives at the top of the file:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Start the external and call `SetParent` on it (we are using notepad here):

```
Process notepad = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
notepad.StartInfo = psi;

notepad.Start();
notepad.WaitForInputIdle(3000);            

SetParent(notepad.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
```

This should work, but I've experienced some strange behaviour with it, in general, I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: will it work for calculator? for calculator it will be shown in the independent window.