# Grab another window by handle and show it as a preview/video in my form (C#)

Tags: c#

So basically I am trying to capture the output of a render window that is hidden by default to put into a controller application as a preview. I've been told by some people in my line of work that this is possible by grabbing the window handle and somehow putting that as a video on your existing form. But I have no clue how to do that currently (outside of getting the handle itself)

Been looking all morning and a bit yesterday and haven't found exactly what I need yet.

Trying to do this in C#

Comment: Do you have control of the hidden render window? I'm pretty sure that if you don't, then you can't do what you want to do. Windows doesn't draw parts of windows which are hidden or obscured by other windows; it makes no sense to get a graphics surface containing these areas. If you control the render window then in theory you can force everything to be drawn into a graphics buffer all the time, and then make *that* data available to Windows as the window contents.

Comment: Here's a similiar question and answers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758494/how-can-i-run-another-application-within-a-panel-of-my-c-program

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the WinAPI SetParent call.  See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083969/embedding-different-applications-in-a-win-form-in-net/7091363#7091363).